# Turning a list of strings into the names of tables

Tags: python, type-conversion

I'm trying to generate tables within this "for" loop. I'm stuck on what I need to do to allow the string in tablenames to be the name of the table.

```
tablenames = ['t_10', 't_20', 't_30', 't_40', 't_50', 't_60', 't_70', 't_80', 't_90', 't_100']
firstrow = ['10%', '20%', '30%', '40%', '50%', '60%', '70%', '80%', '90%', '100%']

for t, r, in zip(tablenames, firstrow):
    t = [[r, '']]
```

Here's what I ended up doing - I know, it's not pretty (I know there's a way to generate the number of spaces I wanted...it was just not cooperating...also, the cond1 and cond0 lists are odd....)

```
t_10 = [['10%', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '','','','']]
t_20 = [['20%', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '','','','']]
t_30 = [['30%', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '','','','']]
t_40 = [['40%', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '','','','']]
t_50 = [['50%', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '','','','']]
t_60 = [['60%', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '','','','']]
t_70 = [['70%', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '','','','']]
t_80 = [['80%', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '','','','']]
t_90 = [['90%', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '','','','']]
t_100 = [['100%', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '','','','']]


tnames = [t_10, t_20, t_30, t_40, t_50, t_60, t_70, t_80, t_90, t_100]

cond1 = [conditions_list[0], conditions_list[2], conditions_list[4], conditions_list[6], conditions_list[8]]
cond0 = [conditions_list[1], conditions_list[3], conditions_list[5], conditions_list[7], conditions_list[9]]

for t, c1, c0 in zip(tnames,cond1,cond0):
    c1_results = process_exhaust(c1,1)
    c0_results = process_exhaust(c0, 0)    
    t.append(c1_results[0])
    t.append(c1_results[1])
    t.append(c1_results[2])
    t.append(c0_results[0])
    t.append(c1_results[3])
    t.append(c0_results[1])
```

Comment: What's your desired output?

Comment: t_10 would be [['10%', '']]

Comment: Basically, I want 10 tables, each named the same as what the string in "tablenames" is.

Comment: by table, you mean list of lists?  Is there a problem with referencing your "table" by `table['t_10']` instead of just `t_10`?

Comment: Isn't it bad form to start a variable with a '?

Comment: and yes, I need a list-of-lists.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to programmatically create variable names is usually a bad idea. You can do it with `exec`, but a better approach would be to use a dictionary.

```
D = {t: [r,] for t, r in zip(tablenames, firstrow)}
```

Now you can do `D["t_10"]` to get the output you desire.

Comment: What I ultimately want is a table, not a dictionary. I am trying to generate a pdf with ReportLab.

Comment: Maybe you could tell us how you want to fill the data into your table. You show the first row. How will you fill in the rest?

Comment: The rest will be populated with lists that are returned from functions. Overall, I'm pulling an array in from a .csv file and creating a dictionary of individual columns. I then identify the specific indices for the data that I need and do the calculations I need to it. It's only 10 tables, I can individually create them, I was just hoping for a way to do it without all that repeated code.